# How to convert Integer in String and String in Integer in Haskell?

Tags: string, haskell, char, integer, digits

I'm still learning Haskell and I'm really confused with this language... i have to implement two functions `fromInteger :: Integer -> String`  and  `toInteger :: String -> Integer` that translate between Haskell integers and numbers by strings of digits in reverse order, like: `"25" -> "52"`. For the sake of functional decomposition i should first implement `fromDigit :: Integer -> Char` and `toDigit :: Char -> Integer`
that translate between digits and characters.
How should the function look like?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please don't name these functions `fromInteger` and `toInteger`, those are already the names of incompatible standard functions.

Comment: but are named like this in my exercise, i have to write them like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`read :: Read a => String -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:read) and [`show :: Show a => a -> String`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:show) to convert from `Integer` and to a `String`:

```
Prelude> show 52
"52"
Prelude> read "52" :: Integer
52
```

But you do not need to convert values to a string to reverse the order of the digits. You can use recursion and [**`quotRem :: Integral a => a -> a -> (a, a)`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:quotRem) to obtain the quotient and remainder.

You can also use recursing to convert an `Integer` to a `String`. Here we use as accumulator a `String`, and we each time calculate the last digit. This thus looks like:

```
fromInteger :: Integer -> String
fromInteger = go []
    where go ls x | x <= 9 = … : …
                  | otherwise = go (… : ls) …
                  where (q, r) = quotRem x 10
```

where you still need to fill in the `…` parts.

Comment: Thank you! I can only use ++, null, head, and tail.

Comment: @Anastasia: and pattern matching :). You can implement `reverse` through recursion and pattern matching.